# How to handle the wrong JSON content type from web-services using the JAX-RS standard client API?

Tags: java, json, web-services, jax-rs, rotten-tomatoes

I want to use the Rotten Tomatoes API to search for movies.

I have an equivalent fully working application that uses TMDB rather than Rotten Tomatoes.

I use the standard JAX-RS Client, provided by JBoss RESTEasy with the RESTEasy Jackson2 provider (I can't post my API key of course):

```
public MovieSearchResults search(String query) {
    return client
        .target("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json")
        .queryParam("apikey", API_KEY)
        .queryParam("q", query)
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get(MovieSearchResults.class);
}
```

The MovieSearchResults class is simply a JAXB annotated class to bind the JSON.

The immediate problem is that the Rotten Tomatoes API is returning a response with a content-type of "text/javascript" for all of its JSON responses. They've shown a reluctance to change their services even though this is clearly the wrong content-type to set when returning JSON, so right now it is what it is.

The exception I get when I invoke the service is:

```
Exception in thread "main"
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: 
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: 
Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of 
content-type text/javascript;charset=ISO-8859-1 and type class MovieSearchResults
```

So the question is: is there a simple way to get/configure the standard JAX-RS Client to recognise the returned "text/javascript" content-type as "application/json"?

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197973/how-can-i-override-the-decisions-made-during-jax-rs-content-negotiation) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859021/rest-service-returning-wrong-content-type-and-unmarshall) are similar, but the accepted answers appear to use JBoss-specific API and I'd like to do it only via the JAX-RS Client API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is to use a JAX-RS ClientResponseFilter.

The request is changed to register the filter:

```
public MovieSearchResults search(String query) {
    return client
        .register(JsonContentTypeResponseFilter.class)
        .target("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json")
        .queryParam("apikey", API_KEY)
        .queryParam("q", query)
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get(MovieSearchResults.class);
}
```

The filter itself simply replaces the content-type header:

```
public class JsonContentTypeResponseFilter implements ClientResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        List<String> contentType = new ArrayList<>(1);
        contentType.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        responseContext.getHeaders().put("Content-Type", contentType);
    }
}
```